# How do i create a user without password in oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying to create a user without any password by using queries-

```
create user abc;
create user 'abc'@'localhost';
```

but neither of them works. It is given on oracle docs that it is valid to create user with no password by including no IDENTIFIED BY clause.

Please help me with this query.

Comment: According to [this syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF54734) the keyword `IDENTIFIED` is required.  It may help if you can explain why you want a user without a password.  Do you want a user who can login without one?  Or do you want a user that can never login?

Answer (score 4):

Either use:

- Oracle wallet. User is identified via password, but the password is not prompted manually.
- External authentication. CREATE USER XY IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY; The user XY must then have OS account on the DB server.

Answer (score 1):

you can create user without password by using externally keyword  OS authentication of that user is used as password,user should have access permission on database .