# Connecting with Oracle `sqlplus` for a user with no (null) password

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

It seems that `sqlplus` does not do will with an empty (null) password.

```
THIS WORKS: sqlplus user1/passpass@DBB
THIS DOES NOT WORK: sqlplus user2/@DBB
```

From what I can tell, it appears that sqlplus does not like an empty (null) password. Is there a workaround for this?

NB: This is not just a question about avoiding putting the password in plain-text on the `sqlplus` command line.

Comment: How did you create a user with no password?

Comment: I did not create the user. We have DBAs in control of that.

Comment: You need to ask them how they did it. As far as I'm aware you still can't have a user with no password. Perhaps they created it with external authentication; is `user2` also the OS username? (They'd have to have remote OS authentication on to connect via TNS too, which isn't necessarily a good idea.) If an Oracle Wallet is involved they should probably have helped you configure that.

Comment: `user2` is not an OS user. It is not using OS authentication.

Comment: OK, then maybe a wallet is a possibility, but so is them having set a password you don't know, or you've misunderstood. Is there a reason you're asking us rather than your DBA, since they know what they set up?

Comment: @AlexPoole - You are right, I already have a question in to the DBA who should be back from PTO sometime soon. I just thought someone here might know and I could make a little progress sooner.

Comment: Ok, this is over. The Oracle account user actually did have a password, but it was not given to me. Now I have it and things are working better. I still do not know if an Oracle account can be created without a password. Sorry for the disruption.

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlplus user2@DBB
```

then you will be prompted for a password

Did you use either of these?:

- Oracle valet. User is identified via password, but the password is not prompted manually.
- External authentication. CREATE USER XY IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY; The user XY must then have OS account on the DB server.

the user should be automatically validated without password in these cases.

Comment: Randy - The point is that `user2` does not have a password. It is empty (null). Yes, this will prompt for a password, but it will not accept an `Enter` key with no text. Besides, this needs to go into a script where there is no human interaction. Yes, I know this should be considered a security risk. I didn't make the DBA rules during this development period.

Comment: Shouldn't you give [attribution for that copied text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266015/266304)?

Comment: @Randy, links are not frowned upon. Answers that are *nothing but* links are frowned upon.